# Why do we need an unused char array for a successfull bind?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bind, can-bus

We're currently developing a small tool that reads CAN-messages and evaluates the data contained. The `bind()` command doesn't return 0 (for a successfull bind) when the char array `empty` is too short, too long or not present. This bug is present in the shortened program below.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>     // socket, bind, PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW
#include <linux/if.h>       // ifreq
#include <linux/can.h>      // sockaddr_can, CAN_RAW
#include <stdio.h>          // printf

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int socketFd = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    char empty[5];     // change length or comment out to provoke the error

    if(bind(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to bind the CAN-socket.\n");
    }
}
```

The behaviour changes with the length of our char array `empty`. 
For example `[5]` works, while `[24]` doesn't.
We tested this with GCC 5.4.0 and 7.2.0 which both showed this behaviour.
Under GCC 5.3.0 the presence and lentgh of `empty` do not influence our `bind()`.

For reference we used

```
gcc main.c
./a.out
```

Why do we need an unused char array with GCC 5.4.0 and 7.2.0 for a successfull bind?

Comment: `addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;` is undefined behavior. You've never initialized `ifr_ifindex`.

Comment: This sort of thing **can** be a symptom of *undefined behaviour* although I don't know what.

Comment: should make sure all of `addr` is populated properly.

Comment: You should start with `memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr); memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof ifr);` and then set `ifr_ifr_ifindex` to a meaningful value before copying it into `addr.can_ifindex`.  (This cut-down program doesn't appear to need `ifr` at all, but I imagine it serves some function in the real program.)

Comment: Initialising `addr` and `ifr` with memset fixed our problem. We set `ifr.ifr_name` to our device name and `addr.can_family` to `AF_CAN` but this has been cut out as it didn't affect the behaviour. `ifr` is needed for our `ioctl` which was cut as well.

Comment: regarding: `addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;`  the struct `ifr` has not been set to anything, so this statement is undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `gcc main.c`  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 4):

You're causing all sorts of undefined behavior due to use of uninitialized variables.

You never initialize `ifr`, then you use `ifr.ifr_ifindex`.

You never initialize `addr.tp`, then you pass `addr` as the `sockaddr` parameter to `bind()`.

That it ever succeeds *at all* is more surprising than the fact that the failure depends on the size of the `empty` array. What address are you expecting the socket to be bound to?

Comment: As it's only a CAN socket, you just need the address family AF_CAN and the ifindex of the corresponding interface (or '0' for all interfaces).

Comment: @MarcusS Yeah but which interface?

Answer (score 3):

We followed the documentation found at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt).

In "4. How to use SocketCAN" (approx. line 60) this example is given:

```
int s;
struct sockaddr_can addr;
struct ifreq ifr;

s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can0" );
ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

(..)
```

While it states that no error checking has been implemented neither `addr` nor `ifr` have been fully initialised (like all of you mentioned here). Therefore the given example encounters the same problem as our program.
Initialising them with `memset` like @zwol mentioned to ensure all values are set to 0 before working with them fixes this unexpected behaviour completely.

Thanks everyone.